# golang crontab execute function every day at midnight

Tags: go

I want to execute function using this crontab library `https://github.com/robfig/cron` every day at 12:05PM. This is my current code :

```
cronHandler.AddFunc("@midnight", func() {
fmt.Println("crontab ping")
}
```

How i can execute my function using crontab every day at 03:00AM, time zone +2 ? My problem is current function use timezone of my server, and second problem this library not allow to specific specific hour when execute. How i can do this ?

Comment: The documentation explains exactly how to execute a function at a specified time: https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [cron](https://github.com/robfig/cron) library along with a few minor adjustments to your code.

A few things:

1. Locate your timezone of choice by finding it within a list from the timezone database, i.e. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)
2. Load this timezone into the `time.LoadLocation` or utilize the `time.FixedZone` method if the `.LoadLocation` method does not work for you, see the [time docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation) for more info on the methods available
3. Initialize a new instance of the Cron job runner using the custom location method `NewWithLocation`, see [docs here](https://godoc.org/github.com/robfig/cron#NewWithLocation)
4. Edit your first argument to `.AddFunc` method in order to add a more granular cron schedule, replacing the generic `@midnight` with a more specific `5 0 * * * *` representing *every day @ 12:05AM* or replace with whatever your desired cron execution time is at the new, custom location

Full example below:

```
// pass in your specific zone name, using USA/LA as example
customLocation := time.LoadLocation("America/Los_Angeles")

// initialize new cron job runner with custom location
cronHandler := cron.NewWithLocation(customLocation)

// the 0/24th hour and 5th minute of every day
cronHandler.AddFunc("5 0 * * * *", func() {
    fmt.Println("crontab ping")
})
```

Comment: `0 5 * * * *` is for every 5 am of the day, not the way you comment in the code.